# How to add additional text to matplotlib annotations

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I have used seaborn's titanic dataset as a proxy for my very large dataset to create the chart and data based on that.

The following  code runs without any errors:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")

# Load the example Titanic dataset
df = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

# split fare into decile groups and order them
df['fare_grp'] = pd.qcut(df['fare'], q=10,labels=None, retbins=False, precision=0).astype(str)
df.groupby(['fare_grp'],dropna=False).size()
df['fare_grp_num'] = pd.qcut(df['fare'], q=10,labels=False, retbins=False, precision=0).astype(str)
df.groupby(['fare_grp_num'],dropna=False).size()
df['fare_ord_grp'] = df['fare_grp_num'] + ' ' +df['fare_grp']
df['fare_ord_grp']

# set variables
target = 'survived'
ydim = 'fare_ord_grp'
xdim = 'embark_town'

#del [result]

non_events = pd.DataFrame(df[df[target]==0].groupby([ydim,xdim],as_index=False, dropna=False)[target].count()).rename(columns={target: 'non_events'})
non_events[xdim]=non_events[xdim].replace(np.nan, 'Missing', regex=True)
non_events[ydim]=non_events[ydim].replace(np.nan, 'Missing', regex=True)
non_events_total = pd.DataFrame(df[df[target]==0].groupby([xdim],dropna=False,as_index=False)[target].count()).rename(columns={target: 'non_events_total_by_xdim'}).replace(np.nan, 'Missing', regex=True)

events = pd.DataFrame(df[df[target]==1].groupby([ydim,xdim],as_index=False, dropna=False)[target].count()).rename(columns={target: 'events'})
events[xdim]=events[xdim].replace(np.nan, 'Missing', regex=True)
events[ydim]=events[ydim].replace(np.nan, 'Missing', regex=True)
events_total = pd.DataFrame(df[df[target]==1].groupby([xdim],dropna=False,as_index=False)[target].count()).rename(columns={target: 'events_total_by_xdim'}).replace(np.nan, 'Missing', regex=True)

grand_total = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby([xdim],dropna=False,as_index=False)[target].count()).rename(columns={target: 'total_by_xdim'}).replace(np.nan, 'Missing', regex=True)

grand_total=grand_total.merge(non_events_total, how='left', on=xdim).merge(events_total, how='left', on=xdim)

result = pd.merge(non_events, events, how="outer",on=[ydim,xdim])

result['total'] = result['non_events'].fillna(0) + result['events'].fillna(0)
result[xdim] = result[xdim].replace(np.nan, 'Missing', regex=True)
result = pd.merge(result, grand_total, how="left",on=[xdim])

result['survival rate %'] = round(result['events']/result['total']*100,2)
result['% event dist by xdim'] = round(result['events']/result['events_total_by_xdim']*100,2)
result['% non-event dist by xdim'] = round(result['non_events']/result['non_events_total_by_xdim']*100,2)
result['% total dist by xdim'] = round(result['total']/result['total_by_xdim']*100,2)

display(result)
value_name1 = "% dist by " + str(xdim)
dfl = pd.melt(result, id_vars=[ydim, xdim],value_vars =['% total dist by xdim'], var_name = 'Type',value_name=value_name1).drop(columns='Type')
dfl2 = dfl.pivot(index=ydim, columns=xdim, values=value_name1)
print(dfl2)
title1 = "% dist by " + str(xdim)
ax=dfl2.T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=1, figsize=(8, 8), title=title1)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.0),title = 'Fare Range')
ax.set_ylabel('% Dist')
for p in ax.patches:
    width, height = p.get_width(), p.get_height()
    x, y = p.get_xy() 
    ax.text(x+width/2, y+height/2,'{:.0f}%'.format(height),horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')
```

It produces the following stacked percent bar chart, which shows the % of total distribution by embark town.

I also want to show the survival rate along with the %distribution in each block. For example, for Queenstown, fare range 1 (7.6, 7.9], the % total distribution is 56%. I want to display the survival rate 37.21% as (56%, 37.21%). I am not able to figure it out. Kindly offer any suggestions. Thanks.

[image]

Here is the output summary table for reference

|  | fare_ord_grp | embark_town | non_events | events | total | total_by_xdim | non_events_total_by_xdim | events_total_by_xdim | survival rate % | % event dist by xdim | % non-event dist by xdim | % total dist by xdim |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 (-0.1,7.6] | Cherbourg | 22 | 7 | 29 | 168 | 75 | 93 | 24.14 | 7.53 | 29.33 | 17.26 |
| 1 | 0 (-0.1,7.6] | Queenstown | 4 | NaN | 4 | 77 | 47 | 30 | NaN | NaN | 8.51 | 5.19 |
| 2 | 0 (-0.1,7.6] | Southampton | 53 | 6 | 59 | 644 | 427 | 217 | 10.17 | 2.76 | 12.41 | 9.16 |
| 3 | 1 (7.6,7.9] | Queenstown | 27 | 16 | 43 | 77 | 47 | 30 | 37.21 | 53.33 | 57.45 | 55.84 |
| 4 | 1 (7.6,7.9] | Southampton | 34 | 10 | 44 | 644 | 427 | 217 | 22.73 | 4.61 | 7.96 | 6.83 |
| 5 | 2 (7.9,8] | Cherbourg | 4 | 1 | 5 | 168 | 75 | 93 | 20 | 1.08 | 5.33 | 2.98 |
| 6 | 2 (7.9,8] | Southampton | 83 | 13 | 96 | 644 | 427 | 217 | 13.54 | 5.99 | 19.44 | 14.91 |
| 7 | 3 (8.0,10.5] | Cherbourg | 2 | 1 | 3 | 168 | 75 | 93 | 33.33 | 1.08 | 2.67 | 1.79 |
| 8 | 3 (8.0,10.5] | Queenstown | 2 | NaN | 2 | 77 | 47 | 30 | NaN | NaN | 4.26 | 2.6 |
| 9 | 3 (8.0,10.5] | Southampton | 56 | 17 | 73 | 644 | 427 | 217 | 23.29 | 7.83 | 13.11 | 11.34 |
| 10 | 4 (10.5,14.5] | Cherbourg | 7 | 8 | 15 | 168 | 75 | 93 | 53.33 | 8.6 | 9.33 | 8.93 |
| 11 | 4 (10.5,14.5] | Queenstown | 1 | 2 | 3 | 77 | 47 | 30 | 66.67 | 6.67 | 2.13 | 3.9 |
| 12 | 4 (10.5,14.5] | Southampton | 40 | 26 | 66 | 644 | 427 | 217 | 39.39 | 11.98 | 9.37 | 10.25 |
| 13 | 5 (14.5,21.7] | Cherbourg | 9 | 10 | 19 | 168 | 75 | 93 | 52.63 | 10.75 | 12 | 11.31 |
| 14 | 5 (14.5,21.7] | Queenstown | 5 | 3 | 8 | 77 | 47 | 30 | 37.5 | 10 | 10.64 | 10.39 |
| 15 | 5 (14.5,21.7] | Southampton | 37 | 24 | 61 | 644 | 427 | 217 | 39.34 | 11.06 | 8.67 | 9.47 |
| 16 | 6 (21.7,27] | Cherbourg | 1 | 4 | 5 | 168 | 75 | 93 | 80 | 4.3 | 1.33 | 2.98 |
| 17 | 6 (21.7,27] | Queenstown | 2 | 3 | 5 | 77 | 47 | 30 | 60 | 10 | 4.26 | 6.49 |
| 18 | 6 (21.7,27] | Southampton | 40 | 39 | 79 | 644 | 427 | 217 | 49.37 | 17.97 | 9.37 | 12.27 |
| 19 | 7 (27.0,39.7] | Cherbourg | 14 | 10 | 24 | 168 | 75 | 93 | 41.67 | 10.75 | 18.67 | 14.29 |
| 20 | 7 (27.0,39.7] | Queenstown | 5 | NaN | 5 | 77 | 47 | 30 | NaN | NaN | 10.64 | 6.49 |
| 21 | 7 (27.0,39.7] | Southampton | 38 | 24 | 62 | 644 | 427 | 217 | 38.71 | 11.06 | 8.9 | 9.63 |
| 22 | 8 (39.7,78] | Cherbourg | 5 | 19 | 24 | 168 | 75 | 93 | 79.17 | 20.43 | 6.67 | 14.29 |
| 23 | 8 (39.7,78] | Southampton | 37 | 28 | 65 | 644 | 427 | 217 | 43.08 | 12.9 | 8.67 | 10.09 |
| 24 | 9 (78.0,512.3] | Cherbourg | 11 | 33 | 44 | 168 | 75 | 93 | 75 | 35.48 | 14.67 | 26.19 |
| 25 | 9 (78.0,512.3] | Queenstown | 1 | 1 | 2 | 77 | 47 | 30 | 50 | 3.33 | 2.13 | 2.6 |
| 26 | 9 (78.0,512.3] | Southampton | 9 | 30 | 39 | 644 | 427 | 217 | 76.92 | 13.82 | 2.11 | 6.06 |
| 27 | 2 (7.9,8] | Queenstown | NaN | 5 | 5 | 77 | 47 | 30 | 100 | 16.67 | NaN | 6.49 |
| 28 | 9 (78.0,512.3] | Missing | NaN | 2 | 2 | 2 | NaN | 2 | 100 | 100 | NaN | 100 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `dfl2.T` is being plotted, but `'survival rate %'` is in `result`. As such, the indices for the values from `dfl2.T` do not correspond with `'survival rate %'`.
- Because all of values in `result['% total dist by xdim']` **are
  not unique**, we can't use a `dict` of matched `key-values`.
- Create a corresponding pivoted DataFrame for `'survival rate %'`, and then flatten it. All of the values will be in the same order as the `'% total dist by xdim'` values from `dfl2.T`. As such, they can be indexed.
- With respect to `dfl2.T`, the plot API plots in column order, which means `.flatten(order='F')` must be used to flatten the array in the correct order to be indexed.

```py
# create a corresponding pivoted dataframe for survival rate %
dfl3 = pd.melt(result, id_vars=[ydim, xdim],value_vars =['survival rate %'], var_name = 'Type',value_name=value_name1).drop(columns='Type')
dfl4 = dfl3.pivot(index=ydim, columns=xdim, values=value_name1)

# flatten dfl4.T in column order
dfl4_flattened = dfl4.T.to_numpy().flatten(order='F')

for i, p in enumerate(ax.patches):
    width, height = p.get_width(), p.get_height()
    x, y = p.get_xy() 
    
    # only print values when height is not 0
    if height != 0:
        
        # create the text string
        text = f'{height:.0f}%, {dfl4_flattened[i]:.0f}%'
        
        # annotate the bar segments
        ax.text(x+width/2, y+height/2, text, horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')
```

[image]

### Notes

- Here we can see `dfl2.T` and `dfl4.T`

```py
# dfl2.T
fare_ord_grp  0 (-0.1, 7.6]  1 (7.6, 7.9]  2 (7.9, 8.0]  3 (8.0, 10.5]  4 (10.5, 14.5]  5 (14.5, 21.7]  6 (21.7, 27.0]  7 (27.0, 39.7]  8 (39.7, 78.0]  9 (78.0, 512.3]
embark_town                                                                                                                                                            
Cherbourg             17.26           NaN          2.98           1.79            8.93           11.31            2.98           14.29           14.29            26.19
Missing                 NaN           NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN             NaN             NaN             NaN             NaN           100.00
Queenstown             5.19         55.84          6.49           2.60            3.90           10.39            6.49            6.49             NaN             2.60
Southampton            9.16          6.83         14.91          11.34           10.25            9.47           12.27            9.63           10.09             6.06

# dfl4.T
fare_ord_grp  0 (-0.1, 7.6]  1 (7.6, 7.9]  2 (7.9, 8.0]  3 (8.0, 10.5]  4 (10.5, 14.5]  5 (14.5, 21.7]  6 (21.7, 27.0]  7 (27.0, 39.7]  8 (39.7, 78.0]  9 (78.0, 512.3]
embark_town                                                                                                                                                            
Cherbourg             24.14           NaN         20.00          33.33           53.33           52.63           80.00           41.67           79.17            75.00
Missing                 NaN           NaN           NaN            NaN             NaN             NaN             NaN             NaN             NaN           100.00
Queenstown              NaN         37.21        100.00            NaN           66.67           37.50           60.00             NaN             NaN            50.00
Southampton           10.17         22.73         13.54          23.29           39.39           39.34           49.37           38.71           43.08            76.92
```